# powershell list of lists: entry initialisation done by address not by value

Tags: list, powershell

I've got a list where each entry is itself a list (of strings).

However when I assign a list to the "list of list" entry, the assignment seems to do it by reference rather than by value. That is if the underlying list changes then the "list of list" changes as well.

The code below shows the problem:

```
$work=New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.List[String]"
$group=New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.List[System.Collections.Generic.List[String]]"

$work.Add("One")
$work.Add("Two")
$group.Add($work)
write-host "-->First Add"
foreach ($g in $group) {
  write-host "--Entry"  
  foreach ($ge in $g) {
    write-host $ge
  }
}

$work.Clear()
$work.Add("OneOne")
$work.Add("TwoTwo")
$group.Add($work)

write-host "-->Second Add"
foreach ($g in $group) {
  write-host "--Entry"  
  foreach ($ge in $g) {
    write-host $ge
  }
}
```

I get this output:

```
-->First Add
--Entry
One
Two
-->Second Add
--Entry
OneOne
TwoTwo
--Entry
OneOne
TwoTwo
```

I'm expecting this:

```
-->First Add
--Entry
One
Two
-->Second Add
--Entry
One
Two
--Entry
OneOne
TwoTwo
```

Apologies if this query seems mixed up but I find it hard to describe this problem.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Oddly, this appears to work...

```
$work = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[String]
$group = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[[String[]]]
```

I get the expected output

```
-->First Add
--Entry
One
Two
-->Second Add
--Entry
One
Two
--Entry
OneOne
TwoTwo
```

In both cases they look to be the same `type`

```
PS C:\> $group=New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.List[System.Collections.Generic.List[String]]"
PS C:\> $group.gettype()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     List`1                                   System.Object


PS C:\> $group2=New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.List[[String[]]]"
PS C:\> $group2.gettype()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     List`1                                   System.Object
```

Digging a bit, one contains a generic list (`List'1`) and the other a `string` of `strings` (`[string[]]`)

```
PS C:\> $group.gettype() | select -ExpandProperty GenericTypeArguments

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     List`1                                   System.Object


PS C:\> $group2.gettype() | select -ExpandProperty GenericTypeArguments

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     String[]                                 System.Array
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks!!!
Super that did the trick.

I did have to make a change to the inner loop of the print code replacing "$ge in $g" with "$ge in $g.item(0)" as the change in list $group declaration has introduced another level of indirection.

The complete solution is:

```
$work=New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.List[String]"
$group=New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.List[System.Collections.Generic.List[String[]]]"

$work.Add("One")
$work.Add("Two")
$group.Add($work)
write-host "-->First Add"
foreach ($g in $group) {
  write-host "--Entry"  
  $i=0
  foreach ($ge in $g.item(0)) {
     write-host "$i`:$ge"
    ++$i
  }
}

$work.Clear()
$work.Add("OneOne")
$work.Add("TwoTwo")
$group.Add($work)

write-host "-->Second Add"
foreach ($g in $group) {
  write-host "--Entry" 
  $i=0 
  foreach ($ge in $g.item(0)) {
    write-host "$i`:$ge"
    ++$i
  }
}
```